# Matomo - Tracking without API KEY

Tags: matomo

I start working with Matomo last week and the Analytics plataform is really interesting and gave me lots of hours extra. However its seems that the plataform has a serious problem with the application authentication, **it doesn't have any!** This problem allows non-allowed applications to be tracked, which is not really effective...

But this conclusion is kinda my opinion and maybe i should read more documentation.

Can you guys give me a opinion about this, before going deep in the Matomo Plugin SDK?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean that everyone could send "fake" tracking requests against the API? I am not sure on how to solve this as every kind of token could trivially be caught and then used for the "fake" requests.

Comment: @LukasWinkler Thank you for you answer. If the Matomo plataform hosts an API management applications can authenticate themselves. I don't understand how tokens could be caught if you use good security pratices. Thank you =)

Comment: If you are talking about JS tracking everyone can simply see the token in the source or in the HTTP request their browser is making. In Apps this is probably less of an issue, but one could still MITM the request or decompile the app.

Comment: Putting the token on the JS code is a bad security pratice and MITM with SSL message exchange is pratically impossible :/